# Tidy gives non-standard HTML

Tags: html, xhtml, tidy

I use Tidy to clean and make HTML files compliant to HTML/XHTML. However, output contains non-standard attributes values like :

```
<table id='abc'>...
```

or

```
<input type='button' />
```

(look at the single quotes). How can I configure Tidy to give strict XHTML output? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to the question, however I thought I'd leave this comment to let you know that using a single-quote is perfectly ok - it is well formed XHTML/XML to use either type of quote. As long as it is consistant (always ' or ") I see no problem with it.

Comment: Tidy is written in C and I need to write code in C++ to config, I don't use command line tool.

Answer (score 7):

This is indeed a valid XHTML. You can put either ***double quotes or single quotes*** for attribute values.

Comment: Double quotes are prettier though.

Comment: Its because we are familiar with that.

Comment: Well, double quotes are much better.

Comment: @Viet visually or? Since there is little difference practically.

Comment: Double quotes are not at all better.

Comment: Visually. And if you can see, it's good to have HTML & XHTML files to look alike XML files where attributes are quoted by double quotes.

Comment: You can use single quotes in any XML, not just XHTML. As for visually ... that depends on your font and personal preferences.